# Debug info gone when changing executable's directory

Tags: c, makefile, build, embedded, proteus

I'm still learning makefile and I created a generic makefile to build a simple AVR project. I use Proteus to simulate the application, but I'm having an issue debugging the application when I change the executable's directory. Debugging works fine with this makefile:

[image]

```make
# ===============================================
# Toolchain
# ===============================================
CC          = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY     = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP     = avr-objdump
AVRSIZE     = avr-size

# ===============================================
# Directories
# ===============================================
BUILDDIR    = build
OBJDIR      = $(BUILDDIR)/obj
BINDIR      = $(BUILDDIR)/bin

# ===============================================
# Files
# ===============================================
TARGET      = atmega32
SOURCES     = $(shell find src/ -name "*.c")
OBJS        = $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
HEADERS     = $(shell find . -name "*.h")

# ===============================================
# Flags
# ===============================================
DEVICE      = atmega32
F_CPU       = 1000000
BAUD        = 9600

CFLAGS      = -mmcu=$(DEVICE) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL -DBAUD=$(BAUD) -Os
CFLAGS     += -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS     += -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums 
CFLAGS     += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax
CFLAGS     += -g -ggdb
CFLAGS     += -std=gnu99 -Wl,-Map,"main.map"

# ===============================================
# Compiling & Linking
# ===============================================
all: $(TARGET).hex

%.hex: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@

%.elf: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) --output $@

size : $(TARGET).elf
    @$(AVRSIZE) -C --mcu=$(DEVICE) $^
    
# ===============================================
# Phonies
# ===============================================
.PHONY: all flash clean size

clean:
    @rm -f *.elf *.hex *.map
```

but when I change the generated files directory to `ex: build/bin` debugging info are gone:

**Note:** changes are in Compiling & Linking section

[image]

```make
# ===============================================
# Toolchain
# ===============================================
CC          = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY     = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP     = avr-objdump
AVRSIZE     = avr-size

# ===============================================
# Directories
# ===============================================
BUILDDIR    = build
OBJDIR      = $(BUILDDIR)/obj
BINDIR      = $(BUILDDIR)/bin

# ===============================================
# Files
# ===============================================
TARGET      = atmega32
SOURCES     = $(shell find src/ -name "*.c")
OBJS        = $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
HEADERS     = $(shell find . -name "*.h")

# ===============================================
# Flags
# ===============================================
DEVICE      = atmega32
F_CPU       = 1000000
BAUD        = 9600

CFLAGS      = -mmcu=$(DEVICE) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL -DBAUD=$(BAUD) -Os
CFLAGS     += -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS     += -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums 
CFLAGS     += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax
CFLAGS     += -g -ggdb
CFLAGS     += -std=gnu99 -Wl,-Map,"$(BUILDDIR)/main.map"

# ===============================================
# Compiling & Linking
# ===============================================
all: $(BUILDDIR)/$(TARGET).hex

%.hex: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@

%.elf: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) --output $@

size : $(BUILDDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    @$(AVRSIZE) -C --mcu=$(DEVICE) $^
    
# ===============================================
# Phonies
# ===============================================
.PHONY: all flash clean size

clean:
    @rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/*.elf $(BUILDDIR)/*.hex $(BUILDDIR)/*.map
```

which is weird to me.  Actually, I don't know what happens here. I already included all the flags required for debugging information `-g` `-ggdb`.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/text/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)

Comment: debug information in binaries only exists as filename + location. Therefore, if you moved your binary somewhere else, then most probably the relative filenames are not found